# Getting numbers from Pdetool in Matlab

Tags: matlab

i am solving a heat equation in Pdetool. As a result it builds an image of temperature field. But i need  a matrix of theese values. How i can take it?

```
    % This script is written and read by pdetool and should NOT be edited.
   % There are two recommended alternatives:
  % 1) Export the required variables from pdetool and create a MATLAB script
 %    to perform operations on these.
% 2) Define the problem completely using a MATLAB script. See
%    http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/examples/index.html for examples
%    of this approach.
    function pdemodel
   [pde_fig,ax]=pdeinit;
   pdetool('appl_cb',9);
   set(ax,'DataAspectRatio',[1 1 1]);
   set(ax,'PlotBoxAspectRatio',[1.3333333333333333 1                 6.6666666666666661]);
  set(ax,'XLimMode','auto');
 set(ax,'YLimMode','auto');
 set(ax,'XTickMode','auto');
 set(ax,'YTickMode','auto');

% Geometry description:
pderect([-0.20000000000000001 0.20000000000000001 0.125 -0.125],'Slab');
set(findobj(get(pde_fig,'Children'),'Tag','PDEEval'),'String','Slab')

 % Boundary conditions:
   pdetool('changemode',0)
  pdesetbd(4,...
  'neu',...
  1,...
 '7',...
 '30000')
 pdesetbd(3,...
'neu',...
 1,...
'7',...
 '6000')
 pdesetbd(2,...
'neu',...
 1,...
'7',...
 '30000')
  pdesetbd(1,...
  'neu',...
  1,...
  '7',...
 '30000')

 % Mesh generation:
 setappdata(pde_fig,'Hgrad',1.3);
  setappdata(pde_fig,'refinemethod','regular');
   setappdata(pde_fig,'jiggle',char('on','mean',''));
   setappdata(pde_fig,'MesherVersion','preR2013a');
 pdetool('initmesh')
 pdetool('refine')
 pdetool('refine')

 % PDE coefficients:
 pdeseteq(2,...
  '46',...
 '0',...
 '(0)+(0).*(0.0)',...
  '(7000).*(460)',...
  '0:12600',...
  '300',...
  '0.0',...
 '[0 100]')
  setappdata(pde_fig,'currparam',...
  ['7000';...
  '460 ';...
   '46  ';...
   '0   ';...
   '0   ';...
   '0.0 '])

  % Solve parameters:
  setappdata(pde_fig,'solveparam',...
 char('0','4896','10','pdeadworst',...
 '0.5','longest','0','1E-4','','fixed','Inf'))

  % Plotflags and user data strings:
 setappdata(pde_fig,'plotflags',[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 12601 1 0 0 0 0 1]);
 setappdata(pde_fig,'colstring','');
 setappdata(pde_fig,'arrowstring','');
 setappdata(pde_fig,'deformstring','');
 setappdata(pde_fig,'heightstring','');


 % Solve PDE:
 pdetool('solve')
```

There is a code which generate automatically. If one know how i can a matrix of temp from it, please help!)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all who have been thought about my question. The answer is: 
in the tab "solve" the item "Export solution". Best regards.